# Как найти значение вложенного обьекта

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь сделать helper функцию, в которую первым аргументом мы передаём обьект в котором исчем, а вторым это ключ которой должны получить. Проблема в том что не пойму как можно найти вложеный обьект если я захочу написать например c.x

```
const arr = {
a: 4,
b: 6,
c: { x: 9, y: 8 }
}

const x = keyObjectFinder(this.arr, 'c.x');
console.log('result is ' + x);

helper.js
export function keyObjectFinder(obj, value) {
    if (typeof obj === 'object' && obj.constructor === Object) {
        for (const key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                let x = obj[value];
                return x;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант

```js
function keyObjectFinder(obj, key) {
    return key.split('.').reduce((subObject, subKey) => {
        if (!subObject || subObject[subKey] === undefined) {
            return undefined;
        }

        return subObject[subKey];
    }, obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что строковый ключ объекта может быть абсолютно любым:

```
{'c.x': 1, c: {x: 2}}
```

Поэтому нативный синтаксис не может поддерживать желаемое вами поведение.

---

Вам необходимо вручную разбивать путь к свойству и итеративно получать доступ ко всё более глубоким значениям:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 4,
  b: 6,
  c: {
    x: 9,
    y: 8
  }
}

console.log('result is ', traverse(obj, 'c.x'));


////////////////////////

function traverse(obj, path, separator = '.') {
  const parts = path.split(separator);
  let res = obj;
  for (const part of parts) {
    if (res === undefined) break;
    res = res[part];
  }
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А я бы использовал eval, чтобы не изобретать велосипед)

```js
const arr = {
  a: 4,
  b: 6,
  c: {
    x: 9,
    y: 8,
    'key of bubu %$!#$#!!!?': [
      15, {moo: 100500}
    ]
  }
};

const x = keyObjectFinder( arr, `c['key of bubu %$!#$#!!!?'][1].moo`);
console.log('result is ' + x);

function keyObjectFinder(obj, value) {
  if (typeof obj === 'object' && obj.constructor === Object) {
    return eval( 'arr.' + value );
  }
}
```

Ну и велосипед, без eval:

```js
const arr = {
  a: 4,
  b: 6,
  c: {
    x: 9,
    y: 8,
    'key of bu.bu %$!#$#!!!?': [
      15, {moo: 100500}
    ]
  }
};

const x = keyObjectFinder( arr, "c['key of bu.bu %$!#$#!!!?'][1].moo");
console.log('result is ' + x);

function keyObjectFinder(obj, value) {
  if (typeof obj === 'object' && obj.constructor === Object) {
    let val = value.match(/^[^.[]+|\[.*?\]|[^.[]+/g);
    console.log( val );
    let x = obj;
    for( let i = 0; i < val.length; i++ ){
      let z = val[i].replace(/\[|\]/g, "").replace(/^['"`]|['"`]$/g,"");
      x = x[ z ];
    }
    return x;
  }
}
```